# Dashes Causing SQL Trouble in DBI

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I have a SQL query with a WHERE clause that typically has values including a dash as stored in the database as a CHAR(10).  When I explicitly call it like in the following:

`$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT STATUS_CODE FROM MyTable WHERE ACC_TYPE = 'A-50C'");`

It works and properly returns my 1 row; however if I do the following:

```
my $code = 'A-50C';
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT STATUS_CODE FROM MyTable WHERE ACC_TYPE = ?");
$sth->execute($code);
```

or I do:

```
my $code = 'A-50C';
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT STATUS_CODE FROM MyTable WHERE ACC_TYPE = ?");
$sth->bind_param(1, $code);
$sth->execute();
```

The query completes, but I get no results.  I suspect it has to do with the dash being interpretted incorrectly, but I can't link it to a Perl issue as I have printed my $code variable using print `"My Content: $code\n";` so I can confirm its not being strangely converted.  I also tried including a third value for bind_param and if I specify something like ORA_VARCHAR2, SQL_VARCHAR (tried all possibilities) I still get no results.  If I change it to the long form i.e. { TYPE => SQL_VARCHAR } it gives me an error of

> DBI::st=HASH<0x232a210>->bind_param(...): attribute parameter
>   'SQL_VARCHAR' is not a hash ref

Lastly, I tried single and double quotes in different ways as well as back ticks to escape the values, but nothing got me the 1 row, only 0. Any ideas?  Haven't found anything in documentation or searching. This is oracle for reference.

Code with error checking:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw, {PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 0})
  or die "$DBI::errstr\n";

# my $dbh = DBI->connect(); # connect

my $code = 'A-50C';
print "My Content: $code\n";
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE CODE = ?" )
  or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sth->bind_param(1, $code);
$sth->execute() or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $outfile = 'output.txt';
open OUTFILE, '>', $outfile or die "Unable to open $outfile: $!";

while(my @re = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print OUTFILE @re,"\n";
}

warn "Data fetching terminated early by error: $DBI::errstr\n"
  if $DBI::err;

close OUTFILE;

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

I ran a trace and got back:

```
-> bind_param for DBD::Oracle::st (DBI::st=HASH(0x22fbcc0)~0x3bcf48 2 'A-50C' HASH(0x22fbac8)) thr#3b66c8
dbd_bind_ph(1): bind :p2 <== 'A-50C' (type 0 (DEFAULT (varchar)), attribs: HASH(0x22fbac8))
dbd_rebind_ph_char() (1): bind :p2 <== 'A-50C' (size 5/16/0, ptype 4(VARCHAR), otype 1 )
dbd_rebind_ph_char() (2): bind :p2 <== ''A-50' (size 5/16, otype 1(VARCHAR), indp 0, at_exec 1)
    bind :p2 as ftype 1 (VARCHAR)
dbd_rebind_ph(): bind :p2 <== 'A-50C' (in, not-utf8, csid 178->0->178, ftype 1 (VARCHAR), csform 0(0)->0(0), maxlen 16, maxdata_size 0)
```

Comment: Is the query actually executing? I like to add an `or die $!` after my executes in case they fail.

Comment: You could also try to use `my $code = q{A-50C}` and see if that escapes it properly. Just a thought.

Comment: It is executing, I've tried with or die before and even with a print error, but it completed anyway.  Also I tried your suggestion, but it completed identically (0 rows).  To make it easier on myself I changed my query to instead do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and calling it explicitly returns 1 row --as expected-- all other ways returns a count of 0 and no errors.

Comment: Hmm interesting. What flavor of SQL?

Comment: Get the error reported with DBI's error reporting method. `$!` won't contain errors that occur in the DBI module.

Comment: Does your query work if you remove the dash from the input string?

Comment: I set up complete error checking in the way described here (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/ch04_05.htm) in section 4.5.1.1 (towards the top) and saw no errors, yet still got my count of 0. I did this removing the dash as well; however 0 is expected in that case.  All values in this field will have a dash.

Comment: Include the code that contains the error checking, please. You should never leave stuff like that out when asking a question.

Comment: Changing it to 1 from 0 had no change in output or visible errors.

Comment: Your first snippet should work. Which DBD are you using? (The word after DBI in the DSN) What version?

Comment: Have you imported the DBI type constants before using the 3 argument form of bind_param?  `use DBI qw(:sql_types);`  More information can be found at http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.633/DBI.pm#DBI_Constants

Comment: DBD::Oracle (v1.30) and DBI (1.616) I think, if that's what you're asking. I added the module of sql_types which now lets me write it { TYPE => SQL_VARCHAR }, but still the same result (no more error at least for doing it that way.)

Comment: 0 rows with the wildcard and like regardless of the fashion in which I call it bind parameter or explicit.

Comment: Take a look at DBI's tracing facilities: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING

Comment: To see the exact value of the bind variable you may try SELECT DUMP(?,16) FROM DUAL

Comment: Ran a trace (Ignore that its p2):     `-> bind_param for DBD::Oracle::st (DBI::st=HASH(0x22fbcc0)~0x3bcf48 2 'A-50C' HASH(0x22fbac8)) thr#3b66c8
dbd_bind_ph(1): bind :p2 <== 'A-50C' (type 0 (DEFAULT (varchar)), attribs: HASH(0x22fbac8))
dbd_rebind_ph_char() (1): bind :p2 <== 'A-50C' (size 5/16/0, ptype 4(VARCHAR), otype 1 )
dbd_rebind_ph_char() (2): bind :p2 <== ''A-50' (size 5/16, otype 1(VARCHAR), indp 0, at_exec 1)
   bind :p2 as ftype 1 (VARCHAR)
dbd_rebind_ph(): bind :p2 <== 'A-50C' (in, not-utf8, csid 178->0->178, ftype 1 (VARCHAR), csform 0(0)->0(0), maxlen 16, maxdata_size 0)`

Comment: DUMP results: `Typ=1 Len=5: 41,2d,35,30,43
`

Comment: Can you add that to the question including line breaks?

Comment: Updated the original question

Comment: What results do you get from `my $code = 'A-50C'; $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DUMP('A-50C') col1, DUMP(?) col2 FROM DUAL"); $sth->execute($code);`? do both dumps contain the same results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is likely a result of comparing `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` data together.

The `CHAR` data type is notorious (and should be avoided), because it stores data in fixed-length format. It should never be used for holding varying-length data. In your case, data stored in the `ACC_TYPE` column will always take up 10 characters of storage. When you store a value whose length is less than the size of the column, like `A-50C`, the database will implicitly pad the string up to 10 characters, so the actual value stored becomes `A-50C_____` (where `_` represents a whitespace).

Your first query works because when you use a hard-code literal, Oracle will automatically right-pad the value for you (`A-50C` -> `A-50C_____`). However, in your second query where you use bind variables, you're comparing a `VARCHAR` against a `CHAR` and no auto-padding will happen.

As a quick fix to the problem, you could add right-padding to the query:

```
SELECT STATUS_CODE FROM MyTable WHERE ACC_TYPE = rpad(?, 10)
```

A long-term solution would be to avoid using the `CHAR` data type in your table definitions and switch to `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: Interesting solution.  In this case, I do not have control over the database to change data types, but the explanation definitely makes sense and the implementation works.

Answer (score 2):

As your DBI_TRACE revealed, the `ACC_TYPE` column is CHAR(10) but the bound parameter is understood as VARCHAR.

When comparing CHAR, NCHAR, or literal strings to one another, trailing blanks are effectively ignored.  (Remember, CHAR(10) means that `ACC_TYPE` values are padded to 10 characters long.)  Thus, `'A   '` and `'A'`, as CHARs, compare equal.  When comparing with the VARCHAR family, however, trailing blanks become significant, and `'A  '` no longer equals '`A`' if one is a VARCHAR variant.

You can confirm in *sqlplus* or via quick DBI query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE CAST('A' AS CHAR(2)) = 'A'; -- or CAST AS CHAR(whatever)
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE CAST('A' AS CHAR(2)) = CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(1));
```

(Oracle terms these [blank-padded and nonpadded comparison semantics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#BABJJGBI), since the actual behavior per the ANSI-92 spec is to pad the shorter CHAR or literal to the length of the longer and then compare.  The effective behavior, whatever the name, is that one ignores trailing blanks and the other does not.)

As [@MickMnemonic suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31552109/132382), RPAD()ing the bound value will work, or, better, altering the column type to VARCHAR.  You could also `CAST(? AS CHAR(10))`.  TRIM(TRAILING FROM ACC_TYPE) would work, too, at the cost of ignoring any index on that column.